# Proof of a limit using Archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I made a proof of the value of a limit using Archimedean property. I would like to know if my proof is correct.

We have $ f(n) = \frac{n^2 +2n +3}{4n^2 +2n}\ $ defined on the natural numbers and the limit $ \lim_{n \to \infty }f(n)  $. The value of the limit is clearly $ 1/4 $

So we begin : Let $ \epsilon\ \gt\ 0$. By Archimedean property there exist $ N \gt\ \frac{3}{\epsilon}\ $. If $ n \geq\ N $ then :

$ \vert\ \frac{n^2 +2n +3}{4n^2 +2n} - 1/4 \vert\ $ = $ \frac{n^2 +2n +3}{4n^2 +2n}\ - 1/4 $ = $ \frac{3(n+2)}{4n(2n+1)}\ $  $\leq$ $ \frac{3}{4n}\ $ $\leq\ \frac{3}{4N}\ $ $ \lt\ \frac{3}{N}\ $ $\lt\ \epsilon\ $ . Therefore the value of the limit is $ 1/4 $.

This is my work on this limit. Its correct? Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm going to be hyperpicky: What justifies the inequality ${3(n+2)\over4n(2n+1)}\le{3\over4n}$?

Comment: That (n +2) <= ( 2n +1) for all naturals

Comment: Good answer (and quick!).

Comment: The only slightly strange thing is that you stripped off the absolute value sign too soon. It's true, the stuff inside the absolute value sign is positive and so you can strip the sign off, *but* you don't know that until you get to the expression $\frac{3(n+2)}{4n(2n+1)}$.